# How to search the MySQL entries shown as decimal numeric character reference(NCR) &#xxxxx?

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, unicode-escapes, ncr

When I am searching my MySQL database with some query like:

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mytable.title LIKE '%副教授%';`

("副教授" are three Chinese characters, whose decimal numeric character reference, NCR, is "`&#21103;&#25945;&#25480;`"), I got no result.

By looking into the phpMyadmin and browsing "mytable", the should-be-found entry is shown as "`&#21103;&#25945;&#25480;`". I think that is the reason for the failure of search.

Not all the entries in the same column are numeric character reference and some of them are just normal. Here is one pic of the table column shown in phpMySQLAdmin.

[image]

I wonder how I could search for all entries in my table in MySQL using one format regardless if there are shown in NCR or not. Or should I convert the NCR entries by running some script? Thanks.

Comment: You have the numerical encoding for the [unicode](http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=%E5%89%AF%E6%95%99%E6%8E%88); you should be using utf8, hex e589afe69599e68e88

Comment: NCR is not searchable when using `副教授`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your database table encoding should be `utf-8` and when you insert new data you should run `set names 'utf-8'` query before insertion and this will contain all your data.